# Debugging Issue, advice required: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, iis

I've seen this question all over the site with varying levels of feedback and troubleshooting steps, my issue however is **the error only presents itself when the web application is compiled and published to the web-server**

The stack trace is below:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +14300177
   System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +350
   System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value) +168
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +4229
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

As you can see, there's very little to work with and since all the code is compiled I'm not sure where to start. I can't even show the code as there are 100's of lines and I don't expect SO community to do my work but I would really appreciate some guidance on techniques to identify the problematic code.

**EDIT** I received assistance on the above error however there is another that is showing up. This time it relates to an integer not being in a correct format, what's confusing is that the variable is an `int`, it's assigned value is from a class that returns an `int` value. The class mentioned in the stack trace uses an `int` parameter which I've checked is in the correct format as well. I've even had a look at the stored procedure that the class calls (on the QA server) and that too takes an int.

The most confusing aspect of it all is that the **error doesn't present itself on my dev machine when running through Visual Studio or**, once compiled, **through IIS** **but only when I upload to the QA Server**, it seems like it's fraught with issues.

New stack trace is below:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +14300177
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +305
   WebPortalDL.Supplier.ManageSupplier.GetSuppliersByBranchID(Int32 BranchID) +1645
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +7406
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

Again, what I really want is advice or a method/technique to debug this sort of issue, help is great but if it recurs then I'm stuck having to post again rather than knowing what to do.

Comment: Where is your code? You need to provide something.

Comment: Did you try researching the error? Chances are it's a decimal that's being parsed according to the server's locale, and the input doesn't match that locale (`42.75` -> `42,75`).

Comment: Find where you're calling `Convert.ToDecimal` in `Page_Load` in (probably) `default.aspx.cs`

Comment: @TommyNaidich Thanks for the quick reply, the c# code file has nearly 850 lines, I don't even know where to start this is why I'm asking for advice on how to debug this issue rather than asking for an answer

Comment: @Daniel You'll have to find out where this is coming from - try looking for any lines within your Page_Load event that call System.Convert.ToDecimal

Comment: Thanks, what is the best when converting session variables / SQL results to Decimal? I have code like this: `Convert.ToDecimal(drDebtor3["due"])` ; this: `Convert.ToDecimal(ASPxRRSupllier.Text)` and have also seen `Convert.ToDecimal(drDebtor2["DebtorPayments"]).ToString())`

Comment: Any chance to change those converts to `TryParse`?. It won't throw an exception

Comment: @Daniel What is the exact value in `ASPxRRSupllier.Text`? Like CodeCaster said: probably a decimal comma versus decimal dot issue.

Comment: @HansKesting it's a formatted string - I'm guessing you're right here! The formatted output would match "#,###,##0.00"

Comment: @HansKesting it was that `ASPxRRSupllier.Text` I've adjusted the code and it works much better. Do you have any idea why this issue didn't appear when running the uncompiled code through Visual Studio?